# Javascript array, modify values for all keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, object

I have an array of this format:

```
array [ object{key1: v1, key2: v2}, object{key1: v3, key2: v4} ]
```

right now, to change the value of each object, where it is key is lets say, key1 to v2, I am looping over each object, like this

```
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
   array[i][key1] = v2;
}
```

is there a faster way of doing this? for example is it possible to pass an array instead of i like so

```
 i= [0,1];
 array[i][key1] = v2;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is using `map()`:

```
var arr = [ {key1: 'v1', key2: 'v2'}, {key1: 'v3', key2: 'v4'} ];
arr = arr.map(function(x) { x.key1 = 'foo'; return x; });

// arr is now: [ {key1: 'foo', key2: 'v2'}, {key1: 'foo', key2: 'v4'} ];
```

The above code will change the value corresponding to the key 'key1' of each object in the array.

Comment: lets say the name of the key was stored in some variable (var J) how would I implement this

Comment: Then you'd replace `x.key1` with `x[j]` inside `map()`

Comment: It makes no sense at all to use `map` like that, and moreover it's misleading to anyone reading the code later.

Answer (score 1):

> is there a faster way of doing this?

Not particularly (certainly [the currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17109996/157247) isn't remotely faster).

You could speed it up ***slightly*** by looping backward so you don't have to constantly re-check the length of the array:

```
for(var i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
   array[i][key1] = v2;
}
```

If you meant *more concise* rather than *faster* you could use `forEach`:

```
array.forEach(function(entry) { entry[key1] = v2; });
```

...or with an ES2015+ arrow function:

```
array.forEach(entry => { entry[key1] = v2; });
```

Or using ES2015+'s `for-of` (**not** `for-in`) loop:

```
for (const entry of array) {
    entry[key1] = v2;
}
```

All of those will likely have worse performance than your original. It won't matter in 99.9999999% of use cases. :-)

Comment: +1 for the reverse looping for any minute gain if at all (for really huge arrays, it probably will) . Btw, my answer is 5 years old. Now when I look at it, it doesn't make much sense even to me tbh. :)

Comment: @techfoobar: LOL :-) I've had that reaction to old answers of mine.

Answer (score 0):

**Used the following approach :**

var arr = [{'key1' : 5, 'key2' : 4},{'key1' : 3, 'key2' : 4}];

arr.map(function(x){ x['key1'] = 20 ;})

console.log(arr);

// output will be [{'key1' : 20, 'key2' : 4},{'key1' : 20, 'key2' : 4}];